# Xamarin IOS: unable to play mp3 from internet

Tags: c#, ios, audio, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I read a lot of documentation regarding this problem, but I don't seen any answer.

I have a Xamarin form app that play mp3 sample music from the Groove music service.

On Android, everyhting workd fine.
On Ios, I'm not able to play the sound. I get the URL and it's not possible to ear anything (I was able to play a local mp3)

I see this problem occured also for people using SWIFT : [How to play MP3 From URL in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33862697/how-to-play-mp3-from-url-in-ios)

I also found several exemple on the Xamarin forum but no sound neither: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/19883/how-do-i-get-the-avplayer-to-play-an-mp3-from-a-remote-url

Here is the code I use:

public class AudioService : IAudio
    {
        protected string FileName = string.Empty;
        protected AVPlayer Player;

```
    public bool IsPlaying { get; private set; }

    public void Init(string fileName)
    {
        //FileName = fileName;
        string second = "http://progdownload.zune.net/145/119/034/170/audio.mp3?rid=0b80911a-ba3b-42ec-b17f-c242ba087024-s4-nl-BE-music-asset-location";
        FileName = second;


        QueueFile();
    }

    public async void PlayStream(string uri)
    {
        Init(uri);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Enter in function");

        Player.Play();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Play sound");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(FileName);
        IsPlaying = true;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(IsPlaying);
    }

    public void Pause()
    {
        IsPlaying = false;
        Player.Pause();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        IsPlaying = false;
        if (Player == null) return;
        Player.Dispose();
        Player = null;
    }

    public bool HasFile
    {
        get { return Player != null; }
    }

    private void QueueFile()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FileName))
        {
            throw new Exception("No file specified to play");
        }

        using (var url = NSUrl.FromString(FileName))
        {

            var test = AVAsset.FromUrl(url);
            var playerItem = AVPlayerItem.FromAsset(test);

            // if Player is null, we're creating a new instance and seeking to the spot required
            // otherwise we simply resume from where we left off.
            if (Player == null)
            {
                Player = AVPlayer.FromPlayerItem(playerItem);
                if (Player == null)
                {
                    // todo: what should we do if the file doesn't exist?
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }}
```

(IAudio just implements playstream and stop)

If you click on the url, your browser will be able to play music
http://progdownload.zune.net/145/119/034/170/audio.mp3?rid=0b80911a-ba3b-42ec-b17f-c242ba087024-s4-nl-BE-music-asset-location

Does any one was able to play mp3 from internet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer in the info.list file. You need to add this to your info.list:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key><dict>
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
<true/></dict>
```

I had the same issue and  resolved it.

Comment: Wonder full it's worked for me ,,Thank you Mr  @Thando Toto

Answer (score 0):

I've made some cleaning for your code :)
This is what we got, including the detecting the end of playing

```
public class AudioService 
{
    #region Members
    protected AVPlayer Player;
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public bool IsPlaying { get; private set; }
    public bool HasFile => Player != null;
    public Action MediaEnded { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Public Methods
    public void PlayStream(string uri)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Player != null)
                Player.Dispose();

            Player = null;
            QueueFile(uri);

            Player.Play();
            IsPlaying = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            IsPlaying = false;
            Crashes.TrackError(ex);
        }
    }

    public void Pause()
    {
        IsPlaying = false;
        Player.Pause();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        IsPlaying = false;
        if (Player == null)
            return;
        Player.Dispose();
        Player = null;
    }

    public void QueueFile(string fileName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileName))
        {
            return;
        }

        using (var url = NSUrl.FromString(fileName))
        {

            var asset = AVAsset.FromUrl(url);
            var playerItem = AVPlayerItem.FromAsset(asset);

            if (Player == null)
            {
                Player = AVPlayer.FromPlayerItem(playerItem);
                if (Player == null)
                {
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(AVPlayerItem.DidPlayToEndTimeNotification, OnPlayerDidFinishPlaying, NSObject.FromObject(playerItem));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Private Methods
    private void OnPlayerDidFinishPlaying(NSNotification notification)
    {
        IsPlaying = false;
        MediaEnded?.Invoke();
    }
    #endregion
```